# How to send email using PHP?

Tags: php, forms, validation

I want to send email using PHP when an HTML form is submitted.

I learnt from a tutorial and made this PHP script, but when I check it in my webmail, I only see email address, subject and message, but no name. What do I need to do to get the name to show up?

Form variables:

```
if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $errors = array();
    $name = trim($_POST["name"]);
    $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
    $subject = trim($_POST["subject"]);
    $message = trim($_POST["message"]);
    $answerbox = trim($_POST["answerbox"]); 

 // ... etc (validation)

if (empty($errors) === true) {
    $headers =  'From: '.$email. "\r\n" . $name.
    'Reply-To: '.$email . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    mail('mail@example.com',$subject,$message,$headers);
    print "<p class='formerrors'>Thank you for your message, I'll get back to you shortly!</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of your "From" header isn't right. It should be in the following Format:

```
"From: Sender Name <sender@domain.com>"
```

So your `$headers` assignment should read:

```
$headers =  'From: '.$name.' <'.$email. ">\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: '.$email . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Comment: Hi Daniel,
Thank you so much, this is working now. i'm a newbie in php, so wasn't quite sure..
Thank you once again!

Comment: Not a problem. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

You should modify your $headers variable as:

```
$headers =  'From: ' .$name. ' <' .$email. '>' . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: '.$email . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Please read more about `mail` function on php.net over here: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mail.php

Answer (score 0):

Moreover maybe PHPMailer, see https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer is interesting for you to enrich your mails.